# CQL: How to copy filtered rows from one column family to another in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have read about the Cassandra copy command which copies all the data from one column family to another one. 
But suppose I want to move only the rows which are filtered from column family 1 to column family 2 is it possible ?

Like, select * from sample where age=40; gives 10 records and those 10 needs to be put in another column family.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to do this sort of "Insert ... Select" operation directly in Cassandra. Instead you could write a script or application to do the select and insert as distinct operations.